# Need to slice the contents in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

Sir,

I am doing the task on fetching the contents from the xml file.I read the contents from other node but in first the contents are in the following form.

```
<NEWSFEED>
<ARTICLE ID="665875" POSTING_DATE="25-Jun-2012" POSTING_TIME="06:00" ARCHIVE_DATE="18-Jun-2013">
<NEWS_TYPE>News</NEWS_TYPE>
<HEADLINE>Diabetes Can Make a Comeback After Weight-Loss Surgery: Study</HEADLINE>
</ARTICLE>
</NEWSFEED>
```

I want to slice those contents from following line of xml

```
<ARTICLE ID="665875" POSTING_DATE="25-Jun-2012" POSTING_TIME="06:00" ARCHIVE_DATE="18-Jun-2013">
```

Thanks

Comment: What contents do you want to slice? And how do you want them split? Give more details.

Comment: ok sir, I am new to this site.

Comment: I want to get the contents in string such as ID="",POSTING_DATE="" and POSTING_TIME="", and ARCHIVE_DATE=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these. Create XmlDocument object to keep the xml file:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
```

Next use the load method to load the XML document from the specified stream.

```
xDoc.Load("pathToYourXmlFile.xml");
```

Use the method GetElementsByTagName() to obtain the addresses of a collection of elements that match the specified name.

```
XmlNodeList newsFeed= xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("NEWSFEED");
```

XmlNodeList represents an ordered collection of nodes under the specified node.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following code:

```
        string x = "<NEWSFEED><ARTICLE ID='665875' POSTING_DATE='25-Jun-2012' POSTING_TIME='06:00' ARCHIVE_DATE='18-Jun-2013'><NEWS_TYPE>News</NEWS_TYPE><HEADLINE>Diabetes Can Make a Comeback After Weight-Loss Surgery: Study</HEADLINE></ARTICLE></NEWSFEED>";
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(x);
        foreach (XmlElement element in xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ARTICLE"))
            foreach (XmlAttribute attr in element.Attributes)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the contents in string such as ID="",POSTING_DATE="" and POSTING_TIME="", and ARCHIVE_DATE=""

Using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) you can do this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

string xml = @"<NEWSFEED>
                   <ARTICLE ID='665875' POSTING_DATE='25-Jun-2012'
                            POSTING_TIME='06:00' ARCHIVE_DATE='18-Jun-2013'>
                       <NEWS_TYPE>News</NEWS_TYPE>
                       <HEADLINE>Diabetes Can Make a Comeback After Weight-Loss
                                 Surgery: Study</HEADLINE>
                   </ARTICLE>
               </NEWSFEED>";
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
var results = doc.Descendants("ARTICLE")
    .Select(d =>
        new 
        {
            ID = d.Attribute("ID").Value ?? "",
            POSTING_DATE = d.Attribute("POSTING_DATE").Value ?? "",
            ARCHIVE_DATE = d.attribute("ARCHIVE_DATE").Value ?? "",
        }).ToList();
```